# file lines get altered at execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, execution

I have a shell script that contains the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ../setup/MAXCR_setenv.sh
if [ ! -f "/home/MAXCR/extract/MYDOMAIN.sql" ]
then
 ...
```

When I run it, I get the following errors:

```
:command not foundenv.sh: line 17
File /MYDOMAIN.sql not found
```

It is as if the first 19 characters of every command is swallowed by the OS (see below):

```
. ../setup/MAXCR_setenv.sh
 1234567890123456789 

/home/MAXCR/extract/ALNDOMAIN.sql
1234567890123456789
```

This program used to work on that machine. 
I suspect a change in the setup or it is somehow trying to run with the wrong shell but I am pretty lost.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Does your script contain windows-style `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: check for `\r\n` with `cat -vet myScript.sh`. If you see `^M`s at the end of lines, use `dos2unix myScript.sh` to clean them up. Good luck.

Comment: The normal way to run into that problem is: `VAR_NAME="/home/MAXCR/extract"; if [ ! -f "${VARNAME}/MYDOMAIN.sql" ]; then …; fi` where, you might observe, the variable names don't match (and the one in the `[` is unset).  Are you sure you aren't running into that as a problem?

Comment: @shellter `dos2unix` does not seem to exist in the wild anymore. :(  Modern Linux distros seem to instead have a package called `tofrodos`, which installs the programs `fromdos` (which is what the OP needs) and `todos`.

Comment: Actually I did find 1 file that had the wrong EOL format. I was able to fix it using Notepad++. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dg99, you can duplicate the functionality of `dos2unix` easily enough in other tools; GNU `sed 's/\r$//'` or non-GNU `sed 's/^V^M$//'`, vi `':%s/^V^M$//'`, or even `tr -d '\r'` if you don't have embedded carriage returns you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did find 1 file that had the wrong EOL format. I was able to fix it using Notepad++. Thanks for your help! –  STondreau